# How to change width at which sidenav hides?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

By default sidenav hides itself and goes into "mobile" mode at width of 1280px. What is the proper mechanism to change that? I need to hide sidenav sooner than 1280px

Answer (score 0):

Use the MediaQuery Breakpoints to change the value. `gt-lg`, for example - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/xOarZP)

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-lg')" md-disable-backdrop="" md-whiteframe="4">
```

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction):

[image]

Comment: In your code pen example the left nav doesn't seem to stay open at >= 960px as it states it should. Also could you give a concrete example of the media query - I find them a bit confusing in angular-material.css

Comment: I've changed the value to `gt-sm` (min-width 960px) so now the panel will be visible  >= 960px - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/xOarZP

Comment: How do you define lg to be say 1280 to 1500 instead of 1919?

Comment: There's a way to do it programatically - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdMedia